# Given IComparer, Zip two ordered IEnumerable-s, pairing only equal elements?

Tags: .net, linq

I need to iterate two ordered `IEnumerable`-s, `a` and `b`, ordered by a given `IComparer`, "side-by-side", and `Zip` equal elements (equal according to the same `IComparer`).

I need to `Zip` all the elements without a match in the other collection with `null` (or `default` value, whatever).

*By `Zip`ping I mean "return a collection of `f()` call results, where `f()` is a given closure taking 2 parameters, one from `a` and one from `b`".*

`a` and `b` can have different amount of elements, and don't have to match 1:1.

For example:

```
IComparer comparer = ...;

int[] a = { 1, 2, 4, 7, 7 };
int[] b = { -1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8 };

var zipped = EvenMoreLinq.ZipEqual(a, b, comparer, (a, b) => new int[]{ a, b });
```

I expect `zipped` to be:

```
{ {0, -1}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 3}, {4, 4}, {7, 7}, {7, 0}, {0, 8} };
```

Equal elements in `a` and `b` should be matched as much as there is a matching element in the other collection.

It is desirable for output collection to maintain the source order.

Does a library implementation of such exist?

Comment: So would one unequal pair *always* yield two results? What about if the pairs were (3, 10), (4, 12) - would that still yield (3, 0), (0, 10), (4, 0), (0, 12)?

Comment: `@Jon Skeet`, I don't have pairs as input, I get them only as an output (Zip results, more generally). Given the input collections are `(3, 10), (4, 12)`, yes, that's the output I need.

Comment: You're talking about *processing* them in pairs though, aren't you?

Comment: But there could be a matching element *later*. That's what I mean - your requirements are really unclear. Imagine sequences of { 1, 2, 3, 4 } and { 4, 5, 6, 7} - what would you want the output to be then?

Comment: Maybe I missed the phrase "Equal elements in `a` and `b` should be matched as much as there is a matching element in the other collection" or so, but I thought it's evident... Your code does this perfectly :) The answer will be `{1,0}, {2,0}, {3,0}, {4,4}, {0,5}, ...`

Comment: No, neither my answer nor Daniel's would do this, as both of them work pairwise. It sounds like you *actually* want to iterate over one collection until it finds an equal or later element to the element in the other collection. I'm not going to put the work into implementing this until you've made it *absolutely* clear that that's what you want though.

Comment: `@Jon Skeet` Really sorry for that. Updating the question statement, and will clean up my comments afterwards. And btw it wasn't me who downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the answer to Jon's comment is "Yes", an implementation could look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipEqual<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector,
    IComparer comparer)
{
    var enumerator1 = first.GetEnumerator();
    var enumerator2 = second.GetEnumerator();

    var enumerator1HasElement = enumerator1.MoveNext();
    var enumerator2HasElement = enumerator2.MoveNext();

    while(enumerator1HasElement || enumerator2HasElement)
    {
        if(!enumerator2HasElement)
        {
            yield return resultSelector(enumerator1.Current, default(TSecond));
            enumerator1HasElement = enumerator1.MoveNext();
        }
        else if(!enumerator1HasElement)
        {
            yield return resultSelector(default(TFirst), enumerator2.Current);
            enumerator2HasElement = enumerator2.MoveNext();
        }
        else
        {
            var compareResult = comparer.Compare(enumerator1.Current,
                                                 enumerator2.Current);
            if(compareResult == 0)
            {
                yield return resultSelector(enumerator1.Current,
                                            enumerator2.Current);
                enumerator1HasElement = enumerator1.MoveNext();
                enumerator2HasElement = enumerator2.MoveNext();
            }
            else if(compareResult < 0)
            {
                yield return resultSelector(enumerator1.Current,
                                            default(TSecond));
                enumerator1HasElement = enumerator1.MoveNext();
            }
            else
            {
                yield return resultSelector(default(TFirst),
                                            enumerator2.Current);
                enumerator2HasElement = enumerator2.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! I'll only need to adjust the double `yield return` piece to still be ordered (I didn't ask for that, but I'd expect this function to maintain order and it costs nothing).

Comment: @VictorSergienko: But you haven't *explained* the ordering. I'll delete my answer as I suspect the downvote came from you, and that my solution doesn't meet your requirements - but that's because you haven't explained your requirements clearly.

Comment: Please see the comments on the question - I don't believe this actually does what's required, in the end.

Comment: @VictorSergienko: I updated my answer to keep this ordering in mind. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry to both of you, gentlemen. I really believed "Zip matching elements [...] zip every other element with null" was a strict enough formulation.

Comment: @VictorSergienko: Not even close.

Comment: @VictorSergienko: Please see updated answer. It should do what you expect now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for all the misunderstanding. Still, I believe the formulation was formally strict from the beginning, and am taking the above epithets as an undeserved criticism.

Comment: @VictorSergienko: You can't be serious. It should be obvious to you that it wasn't sufficiently explained. Otherwise there wouldn't have been any misunderstanding in the first place.

Comment: ...or it has a simple and obvious wrong answer, or a field of other possibilities. You're taking your implicit idea of "zip" implementation over explicit formulation.

Comment: @VictorSergienko: This is getting ridicioulus. Your formulation wasn't explicit. For starters, "every other element" means "every second element" which makes no sense in this context. Continuing from this we had to deduct what you might have meant, using the available sources to which the meaning of "Zip" belongs. Your sample also lead us down this road, because it didn't show any of the cases that would have allowed us to realize you might mean something else.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The grouping can be avoided but the result is obviously similar to [Daniel's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15902982/659190)

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ZipEqual<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<T> other,
    IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (other == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
    }

    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    var first = source.OrderBy(t => t, comparer).GetEnumerator();
    var second = other.OrderBy(t => t, comparer).GetEnumerator();

    var firstMore = first.MoveNext();
    var secondMore = second.MoveNext();

    while (firstMore && secondMore)
    {
        var comp = comparer.Compare(first.Current, second.Current);

        if (comp == 0)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(first.Current, second.Current);
            firstMore = first.MoveNext();
            secondMore = second.MoveNext();
            continue;
        }

        if (comp > 0)
        {
             yield return Tuple.Create(default(T), second.Current);
             secondMore = second.MoveNext();
             continue;
        }

        yield return Tuple.Create(first.Current, default(T));
        firstMore = first.MoveNext();
    }

    while (firstMore)
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(first.Current, default(T));
        firstMore = first.MoveNext();
    }

    while (secondMore)
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(default(T), second.Current);
        secondMore = second.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

---

How about,

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ZipEqual<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<T> other,
    IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (other == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
    }

    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    var orderedGroups =
        source.Select(t => new { Value = t, First = true })
            .Concat(other.Select(t => new { Value = t, First = false }))
            .ToLookup(a => a.Value)
            .OrderBy(l => l.Key, comparer);

    foreach (var group in orderedGroups)
    {
        var firsts = group.Where(a => a.First).Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
        var seconds = group.Where(a => !a.First).Select(a => a.Value).ToList();

        var limit = Math.Max(firsts.Count, seconds.Count);
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(
                firsts.ElementAtOrDefault(i),
                seconds.ElementAtorDefault(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This passed my tests, thanks! Another thanks for `Tuple`, somewhy I didn't think about it at all. Not sure in grouping performance though - that's an overhead, while we only need to iterate all the enumerables once (they are already ordered by condition).